# How to rotate Element around pivot point in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface, pygame-tick

I am trying to rotate an element (in my case font) in pygame around a pivot point my code is as follows:

```
    import pygame, time

    pygame.init()

    display_width = 800
    display_height = 800

    window = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Dials")

    black = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    green = (0, 255, 0)
    blue = (0, 0, 255)


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 50, True)

#All Images of Dials

tutorial = [pygame.image.load('Dial_Images/tutorial_base.png')]

tutorialInputs = [[1,4,3,4], [1,4,3,2], [1,4,3,2], [1,4,3,4]]

class Dial:
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, inputs):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.columns = len(self.inputs)
        self.rows = len(self.inputs[0])

    def drawDial(self):
        for i in range(0, self.columns):
            pygame.draw.circle(window, red, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
            pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (self.x, self.y), self.radius, 1)

        if self.rows == 4:
            input_1 = font.render(str(self.inputs[0][0]), 1, black)
            input_2 = font.render(str(self.inputs[0][1]), 1, black)
            input_3 = font.render(str(self.inputs[0][2]), 1, black)
            input_4 = font.render(str(self.inputs[0][3]), 1, black)

            window.blit(input_1, (self.x - 4, self.y - self.radius + 10))
            window.blit(input_2, (self.x + self.radius - 35, self.y - 15))
            window.blit(input_3, (self.x - 4, self.y + self.radius - 40))
            window.blit(input_4, (self.x - self.radius + 20, self.y - 15))




def level_1():
   window.fill(white)
   dial1.drawDial()


#all Dials Instantiated

dial1 = Dial(int(display_width/2), int(display_height/2), int((display_width/2) - 100), tutorialInputs)

score = 0

run = True
level1 = True

while run:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)

    if level1:
        level_1()



pygame.quit()
```

The following will create a window and a circle with a black border and 4 numbers at 12 o'clock, 3 o'clock, 6 o'clock and 9 o'clock.

I want to rotate the inputs around the center of the circle. Any pygame function that will allow me to rotate input_1 - input
_4 90 degrees around the center of the circle? I saw on pygame some functions like pygame.math.vector and some other .rotate function, but I wanted the best approach.

Also, if there is a way to clean up the way I code the location of the inputs so that they align at 12 o'clock, 3 o'clock, 6 o'clock and 9 o'clock that would be helpful.

Comment: Pygame drawing is not done by "elements", but shapes https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html .  Shapes like `polygon` and `line` can be "rotated" by transforming the points passed to them

Comment: Rotating font in pygame has been discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007478/draw-rotated-font-with-pygame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rencered text in only image/surface so you can use pygame's functions to rotate image in place (around of center of image)

```
image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, -angle)
```

and later move it to border of circle using `radius` and `angle` starting at center of circle

```
angle = 0 # 90, 180, 270
x = dial_center_x
y = dial_center_y
x += radius * sin(radians(angle))
y += radius * cos(radians(angle))
```

It is good to use `pygame.Rect()` to keep position and size - it has attributes like `.x`, `.y` but also `.center`, `.centerx`, `.centery` so it is easy to center number on dial circle

```
image_rect = image.get_rect()

image_rect.center = dial_rect.center
```

and then you can use `radius` and `angle` to move it to position of 12 o'clock, 3 o'clock, 6 o'clock and 9 o'clock or even 1 o'clock, 2  o'clock, etc

```
angle = 0 # 90, 180, 270
image_rect.centerx += radius * sin(radians(angle))
image_rect.centery += radius * cos(radians(angle))
```

---

[image]

---

```
import pygame
import time
import math

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE  = (0, 0, 255)

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 800
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 800

# --- classes ---

class Dial:

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, inputs, angle_step=45):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x-radius, y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius)
        self.radius = radius
        self.radius2 = radius - 30 # position for digits
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.angle_step = angle_step

    def draw(self): # no need to add prefix/postfix 'Dial' to name `draw`
        #for i in range(0, self.columns):
        # `Dial` means single object so it should draw only one circle 
        pygame.draw.circle(window, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        pygame.draw.circle(window, BLACK, self.rect.center, self.radius, 1)

        angle = 0
        for number in self.inputs:
            text = font.render(str(number), 1, BLACK)

            # rotate image
            text = pygame.transform.rotate(text, -angle)

            # center image on circle
            text_rect = text.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

            # move to border using `angle` and `radius`
            angle_rad = math.radians(180-angle)
            text_rect.centerx += self.radius2 * math.sin(angle_rad)
            text_rect.centery += self.radius2 * math.cos(angle_rad)

            window.blit(text, text_rect)

            angle += self.angle_step


# --- functions ---

def level_1():
   window.fill(WHITE)
   dial1.draw()
   dial2.draw()
   dial3.draw()

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
window_rect = window.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption("Dials")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 50, True)

#tutorial = [pygame.image.load('Dial_Images/tutorial_base.png')]

tutorial_inputs = [[1,4,3,4], [1,4,3,2], [1,4,3,2], [1,4,3,4]]

dial1 = Dial(window_rect.centerx, window_rect.centery, window_rect.centerx-250, tutorial_inputs[0], 45)
dial2 = Dial(window_rect.centerx-250, window_rect.centery-250, window_rect.centerx-250, tutorial_inputs[1], 90)
dial3 = Dial(window_rect.centerx+250, window_rect.centery-250, window_rect.centerx-250, tutorial_inputs[2], 30)

score = 0

run = True
level1 = True

while run:
    #keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)

    if level1:
        level_1()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I changed some things but it worked. I am having a hard time understanding why you used `text_rect.centerx += self.radius2 * math.sin(angle_rad)` and `text_rect.centerx += self.radius2 * math.sin(angle_rad)` shouldn't sin be for y value and cos be for x value. I understand why you did angle_rad = 180-angle to account for moving negatively along y axis to move upward but I'm trying to wrap my head around that logic... anyways Thanks!

Comment: I never remeber if `sin()` should be for `x` or `y` - I used it for `x` and it worked so I didn't change it.  BTW: pygame use different coordinate system than in mathematics- `(0,0)` is in top left corner na `y` values below (0,0) are positive, not negative. In clock 12 o'clock has angle `0` but in mathematics it could have `-90` or `270` because 3 o'clock would have angle `0`